# Handy Travel-SE links and tools

Tags: discussion, tools

We have accumulated a few handy online tools and links specifically related to Travel-SE so it might be a good idea to have them saved and updated somewhere for quick reference. Feel free to edit the CW answer and add your own link, tool or thingamajig.

Comment: See also: **[Tools to enhance, analyse our site, etc](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/420)** - maybe these should be merged.

Answer (score 3):

## `travel.SE` tools

- [Tool to analyse IATA airport code tags](https://gist.github.com/1513820)
  (by [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail))

## Air travel sites

- [Matrix Airfare Search](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/)
  Similar to SkyScanner but less well known. Finds more cheap flights than a typical aggregator but doesn't sell tickets.

## Mapping sites

- [batch**geo**](http://batchgeo.com/)
  Can take a list of places and generate a map with each place pinpointed. Could be very useful for answering questions about multiple destinations in a certain area.

Comment: Note you can't run it from that URL. It's just a single HTML file though, so you can save it to your desktop etc and open it in a browser. But if somebody wants to host it let me know (-: Also if any web designers want to help make it prettier and functional-er (-: